# Magento 2.3.1 Getting JS errror on checkout/#payment Uncaught TypeError: items is not a function

Tags: magento2, javascript, onepage-checkout

I am getting JS error 'Uncaught TypeError: items is not a function' on checkout/#payment step in browser console.
It's slowing down page load.
Please check screen shot.
[image]

Comment: are you getting any solution ?

Comment: No. Din't get any solution.